# GSM connection fails - NetworkManager

Tags: linux, networkmanager, nmcli, gsm

I am trying to achieve the gsm connection through my single board computer. I think I set up everything. Below is the output of the modem info:

```
--------------------------------
  General  |            dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
           |            device id: 10c51b4b5511adedf5c6df0380e7acab4ce64f5a
  --------------------------------
  Hardware |         manufacturer: QUALCOMM INCORPORATED
           |                model: QUECTEL Mobile Broadband Module
           |    firmware revision: EC25AUFAR06A01M4G
           |       carrier config: default
           |         h/w revision: 10000
           |            supported: gsm-umts, lte
           |              current: gsm-umts, lte
           |         equipment id: 861585041067073
  --------------------------------
  System   |               device: /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2
           |              drivers: option1, qmi_wwan
           |               plugin: Quectel
           |         primary port: cdc-wdm0
           |                ports: ttyUSB0 (qcdm), ttyUSB2 (at), cdc-wdm0 (qmi), wwan0 (net), 
           |                       ttyUSB3 (at)
  --------------------------------
  Numbers  |                  own: 61451690967
  --------------------------------
  Status   |       unlock retries: sim-pin (3), sim-pin2 (0), sim-puk (10), sim-puk2 (0)
           |                state: enabled
           |          power state: on
           |       signal quality: 0% (cached)
  --------------------------------
  Modes    |            supported: allowed: 2g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 3g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 4g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 3g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 2g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 4g; preferred: 2g
           |                       allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 3g
           |                       allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 3g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 2g
           |              current: allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
  --------------------------------
  Bands    |            supported: egsm, dcs, pcs, g850, utran-1, utran-5, utran-8, utran-2, 
           |                       eutran-1, eutran-2, eutran-3, eutran-4, eutran-5, eutran-7, eutran-8, 
           |                       eutran-28, eutran-40
           |              current: egsm, dcs, pcs, g850, utran-1, utran-5, utran-8, utran-2, 
           |                       eutran-1, eutran-2, eutran-3, eutran-4, eutran-5, eutran-7, eutran-8, 
           |                       eutran-28, eutran-40
  --------------------------------
  IP       |            supported: ipv4, ipv6, ipv4v6
  --------------------------------
  3GPP     |                 imei: 861585041067073
           |         registration: idle
  --------------------------------
  3GPP EPS | ue mode of operation: csps-2
  --------------------------------
  SIM      |            dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/0
```

It seems like no signal shown on Status section. And the output of the `nmcli con` :

```
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE      
cellular            d811a35a-70fc-3716-84e1-a3578d10cc1e  gsm       cdc-wdm0    
resin-wifi-01       a58e405d-fdc2-3649-9339-5bbaea740c76  wifi      wlan0       
supervisor0         8148d985-dc90-4f8c-8e38-62f83f4f13ba  bridge    supervisor0
```

And the wired thing is that the gsm is always **connecting** (not connected once):

```
cdc-wdm0: connecting (prepare) to cellular
        "cdc-wdm0"
        gsm (option1, qmi_wwan), hw
```

I tried to manually up the cellular:

```
root@6f5afca:~# nmcli c up cellular
Error: Connection activation failed: Network registration timed out
```

Up to this point, I tried everything. I tested the SIM with my phone and it worked properly. I have no idea why it is not connected.

Comment: is the SIM working fine? and does the SIM need any PIN before registering to network?

Comment: @binarysta Hi, SIM card worked fine that I tested on my phone. There is no PIN required to this SIM card.